# nth-child from total table / container

Tags: html, css

I have some divs with the same class (`class="myDiv"`) inside a `.container` and these divs can be basically anywhere inside the container...

I want to target all the divs which have the class `.myDiv` and apply css like this:

- first div should have color "red"
- second div "green"
- ...

My current approach looks like this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e92yspu8/)** (snippet copy below)

```css
.myDiv:nth-child(1){color:red;}
.myDiv:nth-child(2){color:green;}
.myDiv:nth-child(3){color:aqua;}
.myDiv:nth-child(4){color:orange;}
.myDiv:nth-child(5){color:pink;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="myDiv">One</div></td>
      <td>Normal text</td>
      <td>Normal text</td>
      <td>Normal text</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="myDiv">Two</div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td><div class="myDiv">Three</div></td>
      <td><div class="myDiv">Four</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="myDiv">Five</div>
</div>
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

**Actual result:**

[image]

Comment: This is a somewhat common misconception, but it's important to note that `nth-child` does not mean *"nth-occurrence"*. It means it will only apply if *that specific item* is *that specific child*. For example, the color `green` will only apply to any element that is both ***(A):** `.myDiv` **(B):** The second child of its parent.* Your `.container` has two children (`<table>` and `.myDiv`), which is why *"five"* is green.

Comment: Furthermore, given your nested HTML, this is not possible without JavaScript. (Unless of course you wanted to get very specific, like `table > tr > td > table > tr > td > .myDiv { color: green; }`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comment, `nth-child` is not the "nth occurrence", but instead based on specific child of parent element.

However, you can accomplish a similar effect with basic javascript if you revise your CSS to this:

```
.myDiv1{color:red;}
.myDiv2{color:green;}
.myDiv3{color:aqua;}
.myDiv4{color:orange;}
.myDiv5{color:pink;}
```

Then, the following simple javascript will assign the nth occurrence.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    divs[i].classList.add('myDiv'+(i+1));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e92yspu8/11/)

Comment: *@Jason W*, Excellent... Thanks for the *TIP*... I am accepting your answer and upvoting the same.. Keep up the good work